# My Tkinter GUI Window loads as a blank screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For some reason, when I try to run my code the GUI window turns up blank. The console does not show any error and the rest of the program runs smoothly. When I ran it separately, without the other code, it ran perfectly. I used to have the 'time' module too, but then I removed it as some said it might cause problems. Any help would be very much appreciated.

OS: Windows | Python Version: 3.8.4

Modules used:

```
os
webbrowser
random    
requests
bs4 
arrow
wikipediaapi
re
urllib
io
speech_recognition
pyaudio
cv2
pickle
tkinter.scrolledtext 
PyQt5
tkinter
numpy
gtts
pyowm.owm
bs4
urllib.request
googletrans
console.utils
PIL
tzlocal
pygame
```

(I know that is a lot of modules)

GUI Code:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Ida")
window.configure(bg='black')
window.geometry("1500x800")

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

wid = 750
hei = 790

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bg="black", width = wid, height = hei)
canvas.config(highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Ida.png")
canvas.create_image(wid/2, hei/2, image=logo)
window.iconphoto(False, ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Ida_icon.png"))

btn = tk.Button(window, text = 'The creator!', height = 2, width = 10,
                      bd = '5', bg="turquoise", 
                      command = lambda : webbrowser.open("www.gigablitzonline.wordpress.com"))

# Set the position of button on the top of window.    
btn.pack(side = 'left')
btn.place(x= 10, y= hei/2)


txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame, undo=True, wrap = tk.WORD)
txt['font'] = ('Calibri', '12')
txt.configure(height=6, bg = "black", fg = "white")
txt.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
txt.place(x = wid/2-250,y = 625, width = 500)
txt.configure(state = 'disabled')

input_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame, undo=True, wrap = tk.WORD)
input_box['font'] = ('Calibri', '12')
input_box.configure(height=3, bg = "black", fg = "white")
input_box.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
input_box.place(x = wid/2-250,y = 745, width = 500)
input_box.configure(state = 'disabled')
```

Comment: Do not use both pack and place. Use a single geometry manager per widget. In general, learn to use `grid` and prefer grid over pack over place. If you use both pack and place as here, the pack geometry management is discarded and place is used as you do that after.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should finish your code off with `window.mainloop()` or you can simply use `mainloop`

- add this to the very last line of your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Before, I used it at the very end of the program. I added it immediately after the GUI and it worked!

Comment: But, it comes with a catch. The code after it does not work. Anyway to get past that?

Comment: I think mainloop causes all the events between window = tk.tk() and window.mainloop() to be run in an inifite loop, essentially running the GUI programme! Nothing after mainloop is run because it is out of this loop. So your script shows blank if you add mainloop() at the last line?

Comment: I guess that is the problem.

Comment: If I use PyGame for this instead of Tkinter, will the problem be solved?

Comment: i dont think pygame is a gui interface

Comment: I haven't used PyGame, only Tkinter, but I think it's a problem with the overall code architecture/structure,not with Tkinter. You should rearrange your code in such a way, that everything is before the mainloop() and as @patthoyts mentioned in the comments to find the best way to build your GUI

Comment: use pack() alone and tell me wat happens?

Comment: I tried running your GUI with the script snippet you have given with window.mainloop() at the end of it and it works, it is not nicely laid out/packed because of issues others mentioned, but it generates some GUI. Apart from these changes that other said, I would reorganise your code so everything is in the mainloop ( sorry for repeating myself)

Comment: The problem is I have a loop at the end of my program, which is why this is happening, I think. Is there any way to get the code of the mainloop() function?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a compact working version from your GUI code. It doesn't contain serious defect so I guess the problem is not really in your GUI section.

**The possible issues:**

- You don't have `x.mainloop()` end of file. Or the place is not correct.
- The imports are not correct.
- There is a "break/blocking" point before `mainloop()` (Eg.: Long `for` loop)

But you can see below my test code. Perhaps it can help you to fix your issue.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Ida")
window.configure(bg="black")
window.geometry("1500x800")

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

wid = 750
hei = 790

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bg="black", width=wid, height=hei)
canvas.config(highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

load = Image.open("Ida.jpeg")  # Open the picture
my_image = load.resize((500, 300))  # Resize picture to 300x300
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_image)
canvas.create_image(wid / 2, hei / 2, image=logo)

btn = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="The creator!",
    height=2,
    width=10,
    bd="5",
    bg="turquoise",
    command=lambda: print("OK"),
)

# Set the position of button on the top of window.
btn.pack(side="left")
btn.place(x=10, y=hei / 2)


txt = tkst.ScrolledText(frame, undo=True, wrap=tk.WORD)
txt["font"] = ("Calibri", "12")
txt.configure(height=6, bg="black", fg="white")
txt.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
txt.place(x=wid / 2 - 250, y=625, width=500)
txt.configure(state="disabled")

input_box = tkst.ScrolledText(frame, undo=True, wrap=tk.WORD)
input_box["font"] = ("Calibri", "12")
input_box.configure(height=3, bg="black", fg="white")
input_box.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
input_box.place(x=wid / 2 - 250, y=745, width=500)
input_box.configure(state="disabled")

window.mainloop()
```

**GUI:**

[image: GUI]

**Console output:**

I have changed the callback function in the `Button` widget to a simple `print("OK")`

```
>>> python3 test.py 
OK
OK
OK
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have a loop at the end of my code, which is the problem I think.

Comment: Yupp, it can be the problem if it is before the mainloop method.

Comment: Any way to get around it?

Comment: It's hard to say anything if I don't see the complete code (or at least the problematic part of it).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't post it. What info do you need?